# python try-finally

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, finally

Why does the exception in `foo` whizz by unnoticed, but the exception in `bar` is raised?

```
def foo():
    try:
        raise Exception('foo')
    finally:
        return

def bar():
    try:
        raise Exception('bar')
    finally:
        pass

foo()
bar()
```

Comment: duplicate of [return eats exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517060/return-eats-exception)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If the finally clause raises another exception or executes a return or break statement, the saved exception is lost.

Comment: interesting!  where does it 'go', if that question even makes sense?

Comment: @wim: It goes wherever local variables go at the end of the function, I suppose. One way to look at it is that the exception is re-raised at the end of the `finally` block. Since the `return` skips the rest of the `finally` block, re-raising the exception never happens.