# Return in finally block in python context manager

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I encountered a strange behaviour in Python's with-statement recently. I have a code which uses Python's context managers to rollback configuration changes in `__exit__` method. The manager had a `return False` value in a finally block in `__exit__`. I've isolated the case in following code - the only difference is with the indent of return statement:

```
class Manager1(object):

    def release(self):
        pass # Implementation not important

    def rollback(self):
        # Rollback fails throwing an exception:
        raise Exception("A failure")

    def __enter__(self):
        print "ENTER1"

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print "EXIT1"
        try:
            self.rollback()
        finally:
            self.release()
            return False          # The only difference here!


class Manager2(object):

    def release(self):
        pass # Implementation not important

    def rollback(self):
        # Rollback fails throwing an exception:
        raise Exception("A failure")

    def __enter__(self):
        print "ENTER2"

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print "EXIT2"
        try:
            self.rollback()
        finally:
            self.release()
        return False      # The only difference here!
```

In the code above the rollback fails of with an Exception. My question is, why `Manager1` is behaving differently than `Manager2`. The exception is not thrown outside of with-statement in `Manager1` and why it IS thrown on exit in `Manager2`.

```
with Manager1() as m:          
    pass                  # The Exception is NOT thrown on exit here


with Manager2() as m:
    pass                  # The Exception IS thrown on exit here
```

According to [documentation of `__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__):

> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the
>   exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a
>   true value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon
>   exit from this method.

In my opinion in both cases the **exit** is not returning True, thus the exception should not be supressed in both cases. However in Manager1 it is. Can anyone explain that?

I use Python 2.7.6.

Comment: See [return eats exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/517060/222914)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `finally` clause is activated that means that either the `try` block has successfully completed, or it raised an error that has been processed, or that the `try` block executed a `return`.

In Manager1 the execution of the `return` statement as part of the `finally` clause makes it terminate normally, returning `False`. In your Manager2 class the finally clause still executes, but if it was executed as a result of an exception being raised it does nothing to stop that exception propagating back up the call chain until caught (or until it terminates you program with a traceback).

`Manager2.__exit__()` will only return False if no exception is raised.

Comment: I believe it would be clearer with an example. Something like `def test(): try: raise Exception(); finally: return True` and show that calling `test` doesn't raise any exception.

Comment: [In docs here:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) "If the finally clause raises another exception or executes a return or break statement, the saved exception is discarded"

Comment: @Bakuiriu Thanks, you are correct, and I'd be happy for you to edit the answer. I'm a little pushed right now.

Comment: Or the `try` block is in a loop and a `break` or `continue` was issued in the `try` suite. E.g. anything that exits the `try` triggers the `finally`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to understand this is by looking at a separate example that is independent of all the context manager stuff:

```
>>> def test ():
        try:
            print('Before raise')
            raise Exception()
            print('After raise')
        finally:
            print('In finally')
        print('Outside of try/finally')

>>> test()
Before raise
In finally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    test()
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 4, in test
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

So you can see that when an exception is thrown within the `try` block, any code *before* the exception is executed and any code inside the `finally` block is executed. Apart from that, everything else is skipped. That is because the exception that is being thrown ends the function invocation. But because the exception is thrown within a `try` block, the respective `finally` block has a final chance to run.

Now, if you comment out the `raise` line in the function, you will see that all code is executed, since the function does not end prematurely.