# Why doesn't `finally: return` propagate an unhandled exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Why does the function not raise the exception? It's apparently not caught.

```
def f():
    try:
        raise Exception
    finally:
        return "ok"

print(f())  # ok
```

Comment: why [return eats exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517060/return-eats-exception)

Comment: What else would you expect? You can either return, or raise an exception, but not both. You explicitly requested a return, so no exception can be raised.

Answer (score 8):

This is explicitly explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The `finally` clause is executed. [..] If the `finally` clause executes a `return` or `break` statement, **the saved exception is discarded**

Comment: That's the quote I was looking for, +1.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> A finally clause is **always** executed before leaving the try statement.

<sup>@deceze quoted the more relevant part in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38094980/1735406)</sup>

The function returns the string in the `finally` clause and doesn't raise the exception since it returned, and that what gets printed.

If you try to execute:

```
>>> try:
...     raise Exception
... finally:
...     print('yes')
... 
yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Exception
```

Then as you can see, "yes" is printed and the exception is thrown *after* the print statement.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

> A finally clause is **always executed** **before leaving** the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. [...] The finally clause is also **executed “on the way out”** when any other clause of the try statement is left via a break, continue or **return statement**.

That mean, in a function the finally clause will *always be the one that returns*. Even if *no exception* as occurred:

```
def f():
    try:
        return 'OK'
    finally:
        return 'Finally'

f() # returns 'Finally'
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) says:

> A *finally clause* is always executed before leaving the `try` statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception has occurred in the `try` clause and has not been handled by an `except` clause (or it has occurred in a `except` or `else` clause), it is re-raised after the `finally` clause has been executed.

In your case, the exception has not been handled, so should be re-raised after the `finally` clause, but since you return from the `finally` clause, the exception is never re-raised.