# How `return` in `try/finally` kills exception?

Tags: python

I was wondering why Python 3.3 kills the exception because of `return` in `try/finally` statement, take a look at this code:

```
import sys

def action1(): 
    try:
        action2() 
    finally: 
        return       # try/finally doesn't kill exceptions
                     # But with return, exceptions not propagated
def action2():
    raise Exception()

try:
    action1()

except Exception as e:   
    print("except clause")
```

Is this behavior desirable and where can we apply its usage?

Comment: This feature is not unique to python, and exists in Java too

Comment: Also the most recent version of 3.3 is two and a half years old, it's probably time to upgrade.

Comment: second half of this question doesn't feel like a duplicate to me

Comment: @Eric  added [return eats exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/517060/674039) which has a discussion about that part.

Comment: Ok, Part of my question was answered by looking at other questions. But, the other part is still unclear. Is this behavior desirable and where can we apply its usage?