# Try-Finally: Get current returning value

Tags: python, return, try-catch

I was looking at [this list of python quirks](https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2009/10/29/python-quirks/) and was amused that this returns `False`:

```
def t():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        return False
```

After seeing this I saw the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517060/return-eats-exception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164144/weird-try-except-else-finally-behavior-with-return-statements) which presented the reason why, and that's that the `finally` clause will always be executed, no exceptions.

My question is, where is the previous `return` value stored:

```
def t():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        ...
```

Why doesn't this return `None` but instead returns the original `True`?

And is it possible to access the *going to be returned* value programatically?

```
def t():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        ...
        # if returning != None: return False
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to do this without using a variable for example:

```
def t():
    retval = None
    try:
        retval = "Set"
    finally:
        if retval != None:
            return retval
        else:
            return "Not Set"
```

and

```
def t():
    retval = None
    try:
        ...
    finally:
        if retval != None:
            return retval
        else:
            return "Not Set"
```

return `'Set'` and `'Not Set'` respectively.

Comment: Obviously it's stored _somewhere_ so it can be used after the `finally:` clause (assuming that doesn't contain a `return` statement), but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't this return `None` but instead returns the original `True`?

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

> The `finally` clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the try statement is left via a `break`, `continue` or `return` statement.

So this means that if a `return` statement is present in the `finally` clause that value will be returned (since the `finally` block is guaranteed to execute fully, any `return` statement inside it will be executed as well). Otherwise, if the `try/except` block was going to return a value, that value is returned.

This means that

```
def t():
    try:
        print("Inside try")
        return "Return from try"
    finally:
        print("Inside finally")
        return "Return from finally"
```

Will execute exactly as:

```
def t():
    try:
        print("Inside try")
        # start of old finally block, executed "on the way out"
        print("Inside finally")
        return "Return from finally"
        # end of old finally block, inserted right before return statement in try
        return "Return from try"
    finally:
        pass
```

> And is it possible to access the going to be returned value programatically?

No, you can't access the value after the `return` statement in other parts of the code without saving it.

Comment: *"No, you can't access the value after the return statement in other parts of the code without saving it."* Have you got an evidence to back this up, and I'm aware that the `finally` clause is also executed, but that quote doesn't explain why the `try/except` value is returned instead if the `finally` does not return, I'm aware that it does it, the question is why. In terms of answering *why* a walkthrough of python bytecode would be useful.

Comment: Because as @martineau said, that is an implementation detail. For the other question, imagine that all the code inside the `finally` block is put *exactly before* any statement that returns a value / raises an exception (if present). If `finally` returns nothing or doesn't raise an exception, the program keeps going. I think this is explained well in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) (which are linked in one of the SO posts that you provided).